# return new static;

Tags: php

Изучаю ООП в PHP. В [документации](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) встретил такой пример:

```
<?php
class Test
{
    static public function getNew()
    {
        return new static;
    }
}

class Child extends Test
{}

$obj1 = new Test();
$obj2 = new $obj1;
var_dump($obj1 !== $obj2);

$obj3 = Test::getNew();
var_dump($obj3 instanceof Test);

$obj4 = Child::getNew();
var_dump($obj4 instanceof Child);
?>
```

Например: `return 10` или `return 'this string'` - понятно что возвращает, но что возвращает `return new static`? И как это работает?

Comment: это называется "позднее статическое связывание". Функция возвращает новый экземпляр класса-наследника. Т.е., несмотря на то, что объявление функции в классе родителе, вызов её через наследника вернёт объект класса наследника